# Create pie chart statistics with php / javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html

```
 <?php  
 $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "Materniteti");  
 $query = "SELECT Gjinia, count(*) as number FROM Neonatologjia GROUP BY Gjinia;";  
 $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);  
 ?>  

 <!DOCTYPE html>  
 <html>  
      <head>  
           <title>Webslesson Tutorial | Make Simple Pie Chart by Google Chart API with PHP Mysql</title>  
           <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>  
           <script type="text/javascript">  
           google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});  
           google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);  
           function drawChart()  
           {  
                var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([  
                          ['Gjinia', 'Numri'],  
                          <?php  
                          while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
                          {  
                               echo "['".$row["Gjinia"]."', ".$row["Numri"]."],";  
                          }  
                          ?>  
                     ]);  
                var options = {  
                      title: 'Paraqitja ne % te gjinise se bebeve te lindura',  
                      is3D:true,  
                      pieHole: 0.4  
                     };  
                var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));  
                chart.draw(data, options);  
           }  
           </script>  
      </head>  
      <body>  
           <br /><br />  
           <div style="width:900px;">  
                <h3 align="center">Statistikat per gjinine e bebeve.</h3>  
                <br />  
                <div id="piechart" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>  
           </div>  
      </body>  
 </html>
```

I want to create statistics using php or html or javascript. I tried to do one where i combined javascript and php but no luck. I have a database that saves data like gender, age, if the person is transfered from an other city or not, there is an age group for eg. 1 to 2, 3 to 4 etc. In this script i tried to make a pie chart that says f.eg that there is 40% male and 60% female, etc.

Comment: whats the **exact** problem?

Comment: try http://www.highcharts.com/demo

Comment: the problem is that I want to take the data from the database for eg. gender and in base of those data to create a pie chart

Comment: how do I connect it with my database so it can read the data from there?